# Flutter: ModalBottomSheet with ListView.separated() size to content

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using `ListView.separated()` inside in the `builder` of `showModalBottomSheet()`. I would like for the `BottomSheet` to resize based on the number of `ListTile` widgets displayed.

Here's my code:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              isScrollControlled: false,
              builder: (context) => Wrap(
                children: [
                  ListView.separated(
                    itemCount: lists.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        ListTile(
                      title: Text(lists[index].listName),
                    ),
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        Divider(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
```

I've tried wrapping the `ListView` inside a `Wrap` widget, but I got an error because the child of `Wrap` doesn't have a set height. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `shrinkWrap` parameter in the `ListView` widget.

[image]

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 4,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('item $index'),
              ),
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
            ),
          );
```

Comment: It looks like by setting `shrinkWrap` to `true` I don't need the `Wrap` widget anymore because the `BottomSheet` automatically resizes itself to fit the height of the `ListView.separated()`. Is that right?

Comment: That's right. You can remove 'Wrap' widget. I confirmed it works well after removing 'Wrap' Widget.